# How to get collapsible results on solr text fields using solr facet query?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am generating a stats report from solr using  facet queries. When generating exception report , we grouped the exception using its `class_name` field in solr.

**schema.xml**

```
<field name="class_name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" compressed="false"/>
```

**Solr Query**

```
http://ultrasound.zmedia.com/solr/goo/select/?q=exception&version=2.2&start=0&rows=0&indent=on&facet=true&facet.field=class_name
```

**Solr Query Results**

```
    <response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">59</int>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1068" start="0"/>
<lst name="facet_counts">
<lst name="facet_queries"/>
<lst name="facet_fields">
<lst name="class_name">
<int name="com">1068</int>
<int name="zmedia">1057</int>
<int name="pool">120</int>
<int name="processor">130</int>
<int name="server">53</int>
<int name="tldresult">43</int>
<int name="tomcat">20</int>
<int name="user">19</int>
<int name="util">19</int>
</lst>
</lst>
<lst name="facet_dates"/>
<lst name="facet_ranges"/>
</lst>
</response>
```

**Expected Result**

```
    <response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">59</int>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1068" start="0"/>
<lst name="facet_counts">
<lst name="facet_queries"/>
<lst name="facet_fields">
<lst name="class_name">
<int name="com.zmedia.tomcat">20</int>
<int name="com.zmedia.user.util">19</int
</lst>
</lst>
<lst name="facet_dates"/>
<lst name="facet_ranges"/>
</lst>
</response>
```

How can i do this?. I cannot change the datatype , because it's running in production setup.

Answer (score 1):

As the field is text and tokenized, the facets returned would be individual words instead of the Complete string.
There is no other option then to change the datatype or maintain a different field with string datatype and this would need change in Configuration and reindexing.